# CSS file link doesn't display on PHP page

Tags: php, css

My CSS file and pictures link are not working on my PHP page, but when I add a style tag directly in the .html file it works. Also, when I add the path with  tags no styles appear on my browser.

I used some defined paths.

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Path du dossier GLOBE_STORE  define('ROOT', realpath('../').DS);

// Path dossiers app/mvc/public

define('APP_URL', 'GLOBE_STORE' . DS);
```

When I change the link tags to this:

```
<link href="<?php echo APP_URL;?>public/assets/css/landing.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo APP_URL;?>public/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> `
```

In the console there are no errors anymore, the cc is showing in the inspector but all my class variables are empty. Like there is no more code in it.

I added some pictures so you can see my folder structure, the inspector and my browser screenshots links: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12jsIvb_CKa_NKXTSKM_p8sKICPP7WjdQ?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the correct URL you want for the CSS files? Currently it is `GLOBE_STORE/public/assets/css/whatever.css` . This means `GLOBE_STORE` is a *child directory* of the location of your file.

Comment: No public is in GLOBE_STORE

Comment: well then that's your problem. Look at your HTML source code #

Comment: Well no need to sound like that. I'm just telling wha I think it is

Comment: Sorry I'm not intending to sound offended / offensive. Look at your HTML source code and then improve the given URL

Comment: No prolem. I will. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Your url pointing to your css files is incorrect.  It is being created when the page loads based on your `APP_URL` global variable.  Based on the images, the path for your css files thats being rendered when the page is loaded is `http://localhost/GLOBE_STORE/GLOBE_STORE/public/assets/css/landing.css`.  This is obviously incorrect.

Seems like the global variable holding `APP_URL` isn't holding the correct value for your base url.  The variable `APP_URL` is pointing to the string "GLOBE_STORE".

To see what I mean, don't use APP_URL in your `<link>` tag.  Try just putting the url manually and you'll see it works. It's hard to guess, but looking at your screenshots your url for your css assets would be `http://localhost/app/public/assets/css/landing.css` and `bootstrap.css`.

You're doing the right thing by assigning your webpage's base url in a variable, the variable is just incorrect.  Is there a global variable named `GLOBE_STORE`?   What does the rest of this file look like?

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Path du dossier GLOBE_STORE  define('ROOT', realpath('../').DS);

// Path dossiers app/mvc/public

define('APP_URL', 'GLOBE_STORE' . DS);
```

Comment: I try to put it manually but nothing appears. Now I'm using a cdn of style and it's working. But the day I'm going to present the project, I won't have an internet connection(or it will be very slow).   The rest of the file is in config.php. You 'll find it in the app folder . Here is the link of my project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Zkfx9-UGed1ohR9oIax3Hn2zxrkn5_1D?usp=sharing